# Cannot connect to wired connection after clean install (both 14.02 LTS and 15.04)

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, ethernet

I just built a new PC and successfully installed Ubuntu without any errors. However, I cannot seem to connect to a wired ethernet cable. The ethernet works,  because I can plug it into a different laptop and I connect successfully. It seems to be an issue with Ubuntu. The connection symbol at the top right flashes on and off. I will be happy to include any information needed to solve this problem. Here is a few terminal outputs that others have requested:

sudo ifconfig

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr fc:aa:14:e6:63
     inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fee6:6763/64 Scope:Link
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
     RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
     RX bytes:366 (366.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo   Link encap:Local Loopback
     inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
     inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
     UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
     RX packets:395 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:395 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
     RX bytes:35868 (35.8 KB) TX bytes:35868 (35.8 KB)
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: eth0
version: 0c
serial: fc:aa:14:e6:67:63
size: 1GBit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Sincerely,
Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a common issue with the network card. A similar issue was brought up a while back, and may find this helpful. Let us know!

[Realtek Network Card Driver](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204946)

I would also check and see if there is linux drivers included for the motherboard. I just bought a ASUS motherboard and was fortunate to find some.

Comment: Well, judging from the fact that I can't even access the internet, is there any way for me to update the driver that the link you posted suggested I do? No drivers were included with my motherboard, and even if they did, I lack an optical drive to even install them on my machine :(

Comment: Perhaps get the drivers and move them to a USB drive?

Comment: Thank you so much! Duh! I loaded the drivers into a usb drive and loaded them onto my computer using the instructions in the link you provided. May I ask, how did you find out that it was an issue due to my network card?

Comment: I have had similar obstacles when working on a MAAS install and NIC cards wouldn't respond to WOL or configure quite right on IPMI